# Sum up distances in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I have a vector of Points and I calculate the distances between every Point (P1P2, P1P3, P1P4,....P1PN, P2P1, ... ,PMPN).
Now I want to sum all the distances of Point 1 to every other point, then all the distances of Point 2 to every other point and so on (P1P2+P1P3+...+P1PN, P2P1+P2P2+...+P2PN) an put these distances into a vector. I am stuck in my for loop now:

Here is my code:

```
    // Calculate mass centers
    vector<Point2f> centroids_1;

    // Calculate distances between all mass centers
    vector<double> distance_vector;


    for (int i = 0, iend = centroids_1.size(); i < iend; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, jend = centroids_1.size(); j < jend; j++) {
            double distance = norm(centroids_1[i] - centroids_1[j]);
            distance_vector.push_back(distance);
            // Here I tried many things with for loops and while loops but 
            // I couldn't find a proper solution
        }
    }
```

Comment: just add a `std::vector<double> sum_distance` and inside the loop `sum_distance[i]+= distance;`. Btw imho it would be better if you showed what you tried and explain why it didnt work, because its not so clear what is the problem here

Comment: I just didn't know the syntax with `sum_distance[i]+=` and in my work I tried a lot with the iterators i and j but it clearly wasn't the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard library instead of raw loops. It will be easier to read and maintain. Plus, the indices are noise. They aren't *required* for iteration.

```
for(auto const& point : centroids_1)
  distance_vector.push_back(std::accumulate(begin(centroids_1), end(centroids_1), 0.0,
    [&](auto res, auto const& point2) { return res + norm(point - point2); }
  ));
```

Specifically, we used a [range-based-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop along with [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). This is the description of what you want to do. Store for each point the accumulated sum of distances between it and other points.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to add a statement like: "Just add the distance to the vector when it is under a certain threshold". Where would I put the if-loop or does this also work with standard library? It is more difficult to understand for me than the solution below.

Comment: @Grillteller - You'd add it in the `[](){ }` construct. That's a C++ lambda, a sort of function you define inline to do your operation. You can put any logic you want in it, so long as you return the accumulated result at the end (perhaps even unchanged).

Comment: @Grillteller - And I know it requires some more reading about C++. But once you have the syntax for it down, it really is less noisy than using indices.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding `distance` anywhere.After the first iteration of the inner loop, the answer for first point would be ready which you can save.

Also you don't need to find the difference between same points so skip when `i=j`

```
  for (int i = 0, iend = centroids_1.size(); i < iend; i++) 
  {
    double distance=0.0;
    for (int j = 0, jend = centroids_1.size(); j < jend; j++) 
        {
            if(i==j)
                continue;
            distance+ = norm(centroids_1[i] - centroids_1[j]);
        }
        distance_vector.push_back(distance);
    }
}
```